# Cant resolve ipfs-car/blockstore/memory when importing nft.storage

Tags: reactjs, ipfs, nft

Im trying to store my nft metadata to ipfs using nft.storage (Reactjs)
When I import the library as explained in their docs I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec8v7.png)

I read a similar error online for web3storage library and that it is probably a webpack version issue, but there is no solution. Any ideas?
This is how I am importing it:
import { NFTStorage, File } from 'nft.storage'

Exactly as shown in the docs.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please post text rather than pictures of text.

Answer (score 5):

Since there's insufficient info on how to deal with this out of the box, this is how I resolved it. It worked fine.

1. Go to `node_modules/nft.storage` directory.
2. Make sure you have `ipfs-car/dist/esm/blockstore` and `ipfs-car/dist/esm/pack`. If not, install ipfs-car with `npm i ipfs-car`. Copy `ipfs-car/dist/esm` to `nft.storage/src`.
3. Inside `nft.storage/src`, update the `ipfs-car` import statements in the following files like so:

Inside `platform.web.js`, update to this: `import { MemoryBlockStore } from 'ipfs-car/dist/esm/blockstore/memory'`

Inside `lib.js`, update to this: `import { pack } from 'ipfs-car/dist/esm/pack'`

Inside `token.js`, update to this: `import { pack } from 'ipfs-car/dist/esm/pack'`

This solved my problem.

Crude but works.

Answer (score 2):

importing pack from built version should also work but crude as well...the package doesn't work at all without doing these, they should update it...I will send a pull request later on.

```
import { Web3Storage } from 'web3.storage/dist/bundle.esm.min.js'
```

Comment: are `NFTStorage` and `Web3Storage ` the same thing? are we talking about the same issue?

Comment: yes they use the same backend

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded `Create React App` to `5.0.0` (which upgrades to webpack 5) and it's working fine. Some relevant tips [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/).